# What do the Magicka Party Robes actually do?

Tags: magicka

The Magicka [Party Robes DLC](http://store.steampowered.com/app/901679) is described thusly:

> - Tank Robe can take a lot of punishment and help his “friends” get an upper hand on the situation.
> - Rogue Robe is mostly nowhere to be seen in a fight, but now and then, he strikes from the shadows.
> - Support Robe makes sure his groups spellcasting is at its best.

Now, that doesn't really tell me anything, especially the last two points. What are the actual perks/downsides of donning those robes?

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is incomplete, but it's a start.**

- **Rogue Robe**: Reduced health, high movement speed, crouching grants invisibility.
- **Tank Robe**: Increased health, reduced movement speed.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it goes like this:

Each robe that comes with the DLC has a speed setting, a weapon setting, and a staff setting. Sometimes they will have other special characteristics that you will discover or can find on the Wiki.

---

For example, the **Vietnam Robe** is like this:

**Speed:** Normal

**Weapon:** Machine Gun

**Staff:** American Flag (Tosses Grenade on Middle click)

**Other Changes:** None

---

Or another example would be the **Tank Robe**:

**Speed:** Slow

**Weapon:** Claymore

**Staff:** Shield

**Other Changes:** Increased Health

Comment: If I had been able to find the Party Robes' effects on a Magicka wiki (there's like 3 or 4 of them), I wouldn't have asked here, really.

Comment: Look harder: http://www.magickapedia.net/wiki/Wizard_Model

Comment: That page just lists the lore text and the item names of the equipment for each character. That's less helpful than the store page, which at least gives you a basic idea of what to expect.